# How can I use a channel entries tag within an orders received email template?

Tags: expresso-store

I have a need to pull up related information from a different channel when placing an Expresso Store order. For some reason, this isn't working in my Order Received template. Any idea why not?

```
<h1>A new order has been received!</h1>

<h2>Order ID: {order_id}</h2>

{items}
  {title}
  {modifiers}
    {if modifier_name == "Vehicle ID"}
      <h3>Specs</h3>
      <ul>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="vehicles" entry_id="{modifier_value}" dynamic="no"}
          <li>Front Blade Size: {vehicleFrontBladeSize}</li>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
      </ul>
    {if:else}
      <p>{modifier_name} - {modifier_value}</p>
    {/if}
  {/modifiers}
{/items}
```

The email I receive looks like this...

```
A new order has been received!

Order ID: 2

Metal Frame Wipers
Specs

Front Blade Size: {vehicleFrontBladeSize}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the entry_id instead of the modifier_value

Something along the lines of:

```
<h1>A new order has been received!</h1>

<h2>Order ID: {order_id}</h2>

{items}
{exp:channel:entries channel="vehicles" entry_id="{entry_id}" dynamic="no"}
  {title}
  {modifiers}
    {if modifier_name == "Vehicle ID"}
      <h3>Specs</h3>
      <ul>
          <li>Front Blade Size: {vehicleFrontBladeSize}</li>
      </ul>
    {if:else}
      <p>{modifier_name} - {modifier_value}</p>
    {/if}
  {/modifiers}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/items}
```

Comment: But I don't want the data from the order entry, I need the data from a totally separate channel. During the order process, I pass through a custom entry ID using a modifier so my modifier name is Vehicle ID and the value is the entry ID of that other entry I need to reference the data from. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahh okay, that does make sense, you will probably need to use an embed or add parse inwards, if i remember correctly. You should be able to move our template so far into a standard EE template wrapped in an orders tag with either an order_id or order_hash passed so you can use the normal template debugging to see if the modifier_value is being parsed after the channel entries tag.

Comment: SMH - I pulled out the logic into a template like you talked about and it still didn't work. After scratching my head for a little while longer, I had an idea to double check my field names. Sure enough. I was referencing a field name that didn't exist. *sigh*

Works great now! Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working. Now that it is working did you need to use an embed or add parse inwards to the template?

Comment: Neither actually! :-)